# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes 0x85 in position 34: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, solid-state-drive

I am trying to train using the `tensorflow models API`. I get this error when i run :

```
python legacy/train.py --logtostderr
--train_dir=pack_detector/models/ssd_mobilenet_v1/train/ -- I am running this from tensorflow/models/research/object_detection
```

I am running on `python3.7` and `tensorflow 1.16`

> pipeline_config_path=pack_detector/models/ssd_mobilenet_v1/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pack.config
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "legacy/train.py", line 184, in 
>           tf.app.run()
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py",
>   line 40, in run
>           _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py",
>   line 299, in run
>           _run_main(main, args)
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py",
>   line 250, in _run_main
>           sys.exit(main(argv))
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
>   line 324, in new_func
>           return func(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "legacy/train.py", line 93, in main
>           FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py",
>   line 95, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
>           proto_str = f.read()
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py",
>   line 128, in read
>           pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length))
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py",
>   line 98, in _prepare_value
>           return compat.as_str_any(val)
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py",
>   line 117, in as_str_any
>           return as_str(value)
>         File "C:\Users\suparun\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py",
>   line 87, in as_text
>           return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 34: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

0x85 is this character …

It is the character of 3 dots.

I just fixed it by replacing `…` with an actual dots like this `...`

But I replaced it using notepad++

I don't know how to replace it programatically.

Comment: I don't have a new question. I am just telling him how I fixed it this problem in my program.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'utf-8' use this codec : 'ISO-8859-1' (Do it specially if you have imported subprocess)